# ruby gem which validates UK bank accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm looking for a gem which validates UK bank accounts by checking the `sort_code` and `account_number`. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read the help topic, [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topi): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Comment: Did you google? I just did and found https://rubygems.org/gems/banktools-gb